# asm (fpu) normalize - how to optimize it

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, fpu

I have written some x86 asm - fpu routine to
normalize a vector of three floats - here it is

```
    _asm_normalize10:; Function begin
    push    ebp                                     ; 002E _ 55
    mov     ebp, esp                                ; 002F _ 89. E5
    mov     eax, dword [ebp+8H]                     ; 0031 _ 8B. 45, 08
    fld     dword [eax]                             ; 0034 _ D9. 00
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0036 _ DC. C8
    fld     dword [eax+4H]                          ; 0038 _ D9. 40, 04
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 003B _ DC. C8
    fld     dword [eax+8H]                          ; 003D _ D9. 40, 08
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0040 _ DC. C8
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 0042 _ DE. C1
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 0044 _ DE. C1
    fsqrt                                           ; 0046 _ D9. FA
    fld1                                            ; 0048 _ D9. E8
    fdivrp  st1, st(0)                              ; 004A _ DE. F1
    fld     dword [eax]                             ; 004C _ D9. 00
    fmul    st(0), st1                              ; 004E _ D8. C9
    fstp    dword [eax]                             ; 0050 _ D9. 18
    fld     dword [eax+4H]                          ; 0052 _ D9. 40, 04
    fmul    st(0), st1                              ; 0055 _ D8. C9
    fstp    dword [eax+4H]                          ; 0057 _ D9. 58, 04
    fld     dword [eax+8H]                          ; 005A _ D9. 40, 08
    fmulp   st1, st(0)                              ; 005D _ DE. C9
    fstp    dword [eax+8H]                          ; 005F _ D9. 58, 08
    pop     ebp                                     ; 0062 _ 5D
    ret                                             ; 0063 _ C3
    ; _asm_normalize10 End of function
```

[It is my code ;-)  It works and was tested by me]

I do not know x86 assembly to much and I would like to find some
optimization of the above (pure fpu old asm especially without sse 
but somewhat more optimized than above)

Especially I wonder if there is some lame coding in this thing above:
I load x y z vector on fpu stack then count 1/sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)
then load x y z from ram again and multiply by value then store -

Is this an suboptimisation and I should try load x y z only once (not twice)
then hold it on fpu stack count and then store at end ?

Comment: Code like is this is write-once, read-never.  Any debugger shows the opcodes, a good comment is not auto-generated.  Consider a bounty to get SO users to spend the time to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: youre wrong, it is plainly inscribed though asm knowledge is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you suggested and load `x`, `y` and `z` only once. It seems like something that could/should help. Apart from that, I don't see much opportunity for anything, assuming you still don't want to use the approximate inverse square root trick.

Not tested:

```
; load everything
fld dword [eax]
fld dword [eax+4]
fld dword [eax+8]
; square and add
fld st(2)
fmul st(0), st(0)
                  ; (see diagram 1 for fpu stack)
fld st(2)
fmul st(0), st(0)
                  ; (see diagram 2 for fpu stack)
faddp st(1), st(0)
                  ; (see diagram 3 for fpu stack)
fld st(1)
fmul st(0), st(0)
faddp st(1), st(0)
                  ; (see diagram 4 for fpu stack)
; calculate inverse sqrt
fsqrt
fld1
fdivrp st(1), st(0)
; scale
fmul st(1), st(0)
fmul st(2), st(0)
fmulp st(3), st(0)
; store
fstp dword [eax+8]
fstp dword [eax+4]
fstp dword [eax]
```

Diagram 1:

```
st3: x
st2: y
st1: z
st0: x * x
```

Diagram 2:

```
st4: x
st3: y
st2: z
st1: x * x
st0: y * y
```

Diagram 3:

```
st3: x
st2: y
st1: z
st0: x * x + y * y
```

Diagram 4:

```
st3: x
st2: y
st1: z
st0: x * x + y * y + z * z
```

Comment: TNX, I will test it. I didnt know fld st(2) mnemonic. Do you know maybe a way to only get (pop) number from (fpu) stack (with no other operation)? As to 'carmack's' trick i measure it and this was 85 cycles (in c, not asm tested) so was slightly faster (maybe revritten to asm it would be yet faster), will try it l8er - also wil back to RaySphereIntersection routine mentioned before and sse -but later (did not got there yet ) TNx much

Comment: @grungefightr What do you mean by "only get number froms stack"?

Comment: edited. I mean pop, Some codes i was trying to write required pop with no other operation (like stp - only pop without store ;-)

Comment: @grungefightr `fstp st(0)` pops one, you can use `fcompp` to pop two (changes the fpu condition codes, but they're rarely used anyway).

Comment: ok, fstp stores and I do not want to store, was thinking about fcomp, tnx

Comment: @grungefightr it stores to the entry that it then pops off anyway, so that's not a problem.

Comment: :U it surprised me :P Is it legal way of fpu coding ? - was thinking that maybe such fpu coding that requires 'pure pop' is maybe wrong (not lies in some fpu coding philosophy i do not know)

Comment: @grungefightr it can be necessary. Usually an opportunity to pop for free presents itself, but not always.